# Redirecting shows wrong url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working a long time on this issue but I still didn't found a solution.

I have on a hosted sever a number of domains. My primary domain is directed to my `public_html` directory. For my second domain if have created a folder `site2`.

So www.site1.com is directed to `public_html` and www.site2.com is redirected to dir `site2`. So far no problem. Both sites seems to work ok.

But if a navigate to www.site2.com/extra_content the url that is shown is www.site1.com/site2/extra_content. If I use a traling slash on my url, the correct URL (www.site2.com/extra_content)  is shown. So I added the solution for the trailing slash. But it doesn't work.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
#ADD TRAILING SLASH TO DIRECTORY IF NONE EXISTS

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)?site2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !site2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2/$1 [NC]
```

Probably I missed something, so any  help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You’re missing the dot between www and site2.com in your RewriteCond. Plus, you should escape the dot, otherwise it stands for _any_ arbitrary character. (Not saying that will necessarily fix the problem though.)

Comment: Plus, that RewriteRule to add a trailing slash looks rather faulty..

Comment: Ok, But where can I find the correct one?